# Expandable list view change default behaviour

Tags: android

I would like to change the default behaviour of the expandable list view 
from:

```
short click => expand / collapse
```

to:

```
long click => expand / collapse    
short click => select item or child
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems the best solution is to do this with a list item click / long click listener.

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    // click - do something with item       
}

public boolean onLongClick(View view)
{
    // group position was stored in view tag
    int groupPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();

    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
        listView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
    else
        listView.expandGroup(groupPosition);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think (if I remember correctly) these were click listeners on items added to the list (each had a TAG linking back to the group)